# How to add an object before another object as part of a bigger object

Tags: javascript, object, insert

For my web-application I would like to add an object before another object inside a self-defined object....
I did find the insertBefore method, but it only applies to DOM objects.
The object looks like:

```
objTemplate[0].objEntry;
objTemplate[1].objEntry;
                    <= add objEntry here
objTemplate[2].objEntry;
objTemplate[3].objEntry;
```

Now I would like to add a new instance of objEntry before entry 2 in objTemplate.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **`objTemplate`** is an array you can use **`Array.prototype.splice`**:

```
objTemplate.splice(2, 0, objEntry);
```

Or, if, for whatever reason, it's not a real array (and you're using numerical indexes) then you can still use splice the following way:

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(objTemplate, 2, 0, objEntry);
```

This will work for "array-like" objects - note that your object must have a **`length`** property.

Comment: This solution works like a charm!
Thanks!
(were did you find this information? I searched but could not find it myself!)